# sql records in last few hours

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I have records in mysql table and I want to know how many records were in last 3, 7 and 12 hours. What would be the sql for that? My date field in in the format as

```
2010-08-09 09:52:27 
2010-08-09 09:52:27 
2010-08-09 09:52:27 
2010-08-09 10:44:46 
2010-08-09 10:44:46 
2010-08-09 11:58:27 
2010-08-09 14:48:22 
2010-08-09 14:48:22
```

Answer (score 7):

For the last three hours:

```
WHERE column BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 HOUR)
                 AND NOW()
```

For the last seven hours:

```
WHERE column BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 HOUR)
                 AND NOW()
```

For the last twelve hours:

```
WHERE column BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 12 HOUR)
                 AND NOW()
```

If you're wanting to specify a data as a string, use:

```
WHERE column BETWEEN DATE_SUB(STR_TO_DATE('2010-07-08 07:57:45', '%Y-%m-%d %T'), INTERVAL 3 HOUR)
                 AND STR_TO_DATE('2010-07-08 07:57:45', '%Y-%m-%d %T')
```

...though honestly, you could use this just as well:

```
WHERE column BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('2010-07-08 04:57:45', '%Y-%m-%d %T')
                 AND STR_TO_DATE('2010-07-08 07:57:45', '%Y-%m-%d %T')
```

If that doesn't work, then I wonder if the column is storing values as strings/varchar rather than DATETIME.

Reference:

- [DATE_SUB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub)

Comment: I used the following query but it didnot give me the right results

  $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `order` WHERE myDateField BETWEEN DATE_SUB("2010-07-08 07:57:45", INTERVAL 3 HOUR) 
                 AND "2010-07-08 07:57:45"';

Comment: @user295189: Use single, not double, quotes.  And if you're using a string, use `STR_TO_DATE('2010-07-08 07:57:45', '%Y-%m-%d %T')` to convert a string into a DATETIME reliably

Comment: did not work.. still give me just 2 records of same date and time -07-08 07:57:45'

Comment: @user295189: See my updates - this works for me on MySQL 4.1, only thing I can think of is your column is not a DATETIME data type

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that no records bear a timestamp in the future, you could use:

```
WHERE myDateField > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 HOUR)
```

for the last three hours-worth of records, and similarly for 7 and 12 hours.